# Intel Stack Growth and Reference

Tags: assembly, kernel, intel

I have a couple of questions regarding the Intel IA-32 stack. Specifically:

1. When I `push` a value onto the stack, the stack pointer is decreased by the size of the value pushed (`%esp - size`), and the value is stored at the old value of `%esp`.
2. If I then want to read the value back off of the stack without `pop`ing it, I need to increase the stack pointer (`%esp + size`).
3. [A piece of kernel code I have](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L169) is subtracting the size needed from the stack, instead of adding it. It is my assumption that when this happens, the value I want is moving *away* from the pointer address, instead of *towards* it.
4. Because of this, any further read will pick up bad data.

Are my above assertions correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code (__With Comments !!!__) so that we can read it and see what the compiler is doing, and what you think you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrong, the value is written at the new `%esp` value.
2. Wrong, because of point #1: you can just read back your most recent value from `(%esp)`. You need to add to `%esp` to access older items.
3. That code is just allocating a block of memory from the stack as local storage. The block is filled in later.
4. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the IA-32 specification](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf), PUSH decreases the stack pointer and then stores the value at the *new `%esp` location*. Thus, reading the pushed value without `pop`ing it would be just reading the value pointed to by the current value of `%esp`.